# How can I delete a draft answer?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Occasionally, I start writing an answer to a question, get distracted, come back later to a "there are new answers" message, load the other answers, decide they're the same as (or better than) what I was going to write, and I decide to abandon my answer. The problem is, just deleting the text from the answer pane isn't enough - the system saves a draft, which keeps coming back every time I visit that question. Is there a way to delete such a draft?

Comment: Could someone with Powers(TM) please remove the now-erroneous [status-bydesign] tag (and probably add a [status-resolved] or similar)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure when this feature was implemented, but there is a discard option that appears next to the Post Your Answer button after 45 seconds.

[image]

Comment: Yeah - I use that sometimes, but to be honest I'd never even noticed *discard* takes a while to appear. Other times I'm *glad* the system has saved a copy, since I sometimes lose my one!

Comment: Timed and updated.

Comment: It might not run to a very well-regulated clock. But I tested it myself (using my own carefully-crafted text *uiop*, rather than just slavishly copy yours). I didn't exactly time it, but I can report *"discard"* appeared within the time it took me to fetch a glass of wine. Almost certainly less than 3 minutes.

Comment: It appears at the same time that the "draft saved" message appears.

Comment: I'm glad SE is no longer fixing bugs by reclassifying them as features. Well, in this small case, at least.

Answer (score 5):

Only one draft per user is ever saved -- so this draft will be replaced the next time you answer a question, as the draft for *that* question will overwrite this one.